# How to prevent Visual Studio from creating coredumps when my program crashes?

Tags: macos, terminal, launchd

I am using Visual Studio 2022 for Mac Preview version 17.0.

It runs well but a problem I'm having is that after every error, when running the program (in my case a simple console app), it creates big coredumps. Over 1GB.

I already used:

```
sudo launchctl limit core 0 0
```

and Visual Studio just writes the files somewhere else.

Is there any way to disable this? Not just automatically deleting them but disabling them? I cannot imagine that writing 30gb of data in 2hr and deleting it again every day is good for the longevity of my drive.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As opposed to fixing your program so that it doesn't crash?  And no, it's not likely you'll ever notice the writes.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that using

```
            throw new NotImplementedException();
```

generates the coredump file.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Did you mean to edit this into the question as a way to reproduce this issue? It’s not clear how this addresses your question as an answer. ….

Comment: Actually it does not. I would read some C++ tutorials. The dump is if you have an uncaught exception, ie work out what exceptions each line of code you write could throw and then decide how you want to handle each one.